# AAD B2C not skipping orchestration step

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Good day! I have a problem when skipping an orchestration step in AAD B2C.

I'll start at the beginning.

So I have a custom user attribute named `User Tagged`, the type of this attribute is `boolean` and it indicates if the user is tagged or not.

Now in my xml file, I have declared the `ClaimType` of `User Tagged`

Here is the **ClaimType**:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="extension_userTagged">
    <DataType>boolean</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

Now in my technical profile, i've set the default value of `User Tagged` to `true`

Here is the **TechnicalProfile**:

```xml
<!-- Technical profile to set extension_userTagged to true -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="UserTagged">
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_userTagged" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Now in my orchestration steps, I have two steps, The api that tags the user and the step that makes the `User Tagged` to `true`

Here is the **OrchestrationSteps**:

```xml
<!-- # The Tagging API Step -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>extension_userTagged</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ApiTaggingStep" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="TPRestfulTagging" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Setting the User Tagged to true -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>extension_userTagged</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckUserIfTagged" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="UserTagged"/>
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Now comes the problem, first if the user is NOT yet tagged then my `OrchestrationStep` works. But when the user IS tagged, the `OrchestrationStep` order 1 still executes. I have checked the logs and yes, the `extension_userTagged` is there. For some reason it doesn't execute the preconditions. I'm probably missing some things but idk what it is.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you say orchestration step 1 executes, does orchestration step 2 also execute?
Are these orchestration steps in a sub-journey?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I always use:

```
<Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
```

Comment: Hello @rbrayb, yeah unfortunately it doesn't work. For some reason it does not see my `extension_userTagged` claim in the precondition.

Answer (score 0):

The ClaimEquals precondition check performs a **case-sensitive** ordinal comparison.

You have different cases for "true" in the technical profile and orchestration step.

Make sure the DefaultValue matches the Value.

E.g.,

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_userTagged" DefaultValue="True" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
```

And

```
<Value>extension_userTagged</Value>
<Value>True</Value>
```

Since many schema elements only support lower case booleans, e.g. AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true", I tend to use lower case everywhere to avoid this.

It is also good practice to precede a ClaimEquals check with a ClaimsExist check to support the null scenario.

see: [UserJourneys doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys)

Hope this helps.

Comment: "ClaimEquals precondition check performs a case-sensitive ordinal comparison." - This is not correct for boolean claim types, but is true for others such as string. For Boolean the precondition value had to be 'True' (with a capital) even though the claim outputted it as true (lowercase). I believe they fixed this bug now though but I'd always air on using a Capital T for boolean claim equals comparisons.